# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express - creating a ASP.NET Web Site Targetting .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

When I do File->New WebSite & chose C# ASP.NET project - it creates a basic project with About.aspx, Default.aspx etc. This builds fine. However, when I got Website->Start Options and chose target Framework as .NET 2.0, the project no longer compiles.

These are the errors I get

```
WebSite2\Account\Register.aspx(8): Build (page): Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard' does not have a public property named 'LayoutTemplate'.
WebSite2\Account\Register.aspx(9): Build (page): Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard' does not have a public property named 'PlaceHolder'.
WebSite2\Account\Register.aspx(10): Build (page): Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard' does not have a public property named 'PlaceHolder'.
WebSite2\Account\Register.aspx(9): Build (page): Content ('</asp:PlaceHolder>              </asp:PlaceHolder>          </LayoutTemplate>') does not match any properties within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard', make sure it is well-formed.
WebSite2\Site.master.cs(3,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Is there a way to create a default non-empty project which works with .NET 2.0?

[image: My Dialog]

Comment: For LINQ you have to now manually add a reference. For v4 it is pre-referenced for you. That should take care of the `site.master` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow these steps :-

[image]

[image]

or

you can comment

```
using System.Linq;  (from all .cs pages)
```

and
(from Register.aspx page)

```
 <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
```

and try to build then.

Comment: My new web site options look different than yours - I have added a screenshot in my question.

Comment: than follow second step,which i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

read this it tells you how to change the target framwork
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202.aspx

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: I am using "New Website" and not "New Project" - in New website - there is no option to targer 2.0

Comment: Yes, I changed the target framework in the same dialog you show at the end. After that I got the build errors.

Comment: that's normal because you changed the framework and v4 has some updates not inserted in v2 that's why you have to do manual modifications for successful build , or delete the pages like abou.aspx and default if you don't need them and it will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Choose File, New, New Website and change the .Net Framework dropdown list version to 2.0. prior to clicking the 'Ok' button.

Edit: Added screenshot from Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate Edition, not sure if this also applies to express)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I updated the question - I am using Visual Web developer 2010 - I don't see an option to change it to 2.0 before clicking OK.

Comment: Edited my answer and added a screenshot (I think!)

Comment: My new "web site" options look different than yours - I have added a screenshot in my question.